# Enter date of birth

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

guys, I'm doing a problem to enter a date of birth in the format dd/mm/yyyy

The instructions to follow are

1. Prompt the user to enter a date of birth below.
2. Extract the 3 fields by slicing the string into 3 slices. To separate the day from the month, you will need to first use the find() method to find the position of the first slash. To separate the month from the year, you will need to use the `rfind()` method to find the position of the last slash.

I've tried to do string slices and concatenation alongside indexing, but am quite shaky on how to do it, or if I'm even doing it. Were also not allowed to use conditional statements.

```
birthday = input("Enter your date of birth: ",)

day = birthday.find("/")
month = birthday.find("/")
year = birthday.rfind("/")

print("Day: ",day)
print("Month: ", month)
print("Year: ", year)
```

The format expected is:

Enter your date of birth: 30/8/1985

Day: 30

Month: 8

Year: 1985

Comment: try `day, month, year = birthday.split('/')`

Comment: Using `find` and `rfind` instead of split is inefficient. Your code lacks the `slicing` part - you only get _indexes_ - you still need to slice the string into the data you want - what is your problem? Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `rfind()` is a roundabout way to do it. It will work, but you would be better off with

```
day, month, year = birthday.split("/")
```

If your instructor insists on the `find`/`rfind` approach then you can do it this way:

```
day = birthday[:birthday.find("/")]
month = birthday[birthday.find("/")+1:birthday.rfind("/")]
year = birthday[birthday.rfind("/")+1:]
```

It might be that the intention of the exercise is to teach you about slicing strings rather than how to write readable Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you have further processing of date, `datetime` module is useful:

```
from datetime import datetime

birthday = input("Enter your date of birth: ")

bday = datetime.strptime(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')

print(f'Day: {bday.day}')
print(f'Month: {bday.month}')
print(f'Year: {bday.year}')
```

An important **advantage** is that this helps prevent user from entering wrong date, for example 32 as day or 13 as month value.

Answer (score 1):

Read from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) about `find` and `rfind`. They return the lowest and the highest indexes of found occurrences. So you should do instead:

```
b = "30/8/1985"

first_sep, last_sep = b.find("/"), b.rfind("/")
day = b[:first_sep]
month = b[first_sep+1:last_sep]
year = b[last_sep+1:]

print("Day: ", day)
print("Month: ", month)
print("Year: ", year)
```

**Output:**

```
Day:  30
Month:  8
Year:  1985
```

Answer (score 0):

```
birthday = input("Enter your date of birth: ",)
birthday_list = birthday.split("/")
print("Day: ",birthday_list[0])
print("Month: ", birthday_list[1])
print("Year: ", birthday_list[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
birthday = input("Enter your date of birth: ",)
match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', birthday)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Then you can get day, month, year from that.
Please refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score -1):

This works spendidly:

```
import datetime

birthday = input('Enter your birthday in dd/mm/yyyy format')
day, month, year = list(map(int, birthday.split("/")))
birthdate = datetime.date(year, month, day)

print(f"Birthday is on {birthdate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}")
```